# Android 1.5 emulator crashing apparently randomly [WIN DEATH]

Tags: android, crash

I'm getting seeming random crashes (though they always happen at the same time) on the Android 1.5 Emulator (running under OS X). Code is built against 1.5 APIs and runs fine on other versions. App doing the same on an HTC Hero so it appears to be an Android issue rather than just an emulator issue.

By random I mean a screen will display OK for a few seconds and then crash with no user input or state change. In at least one case it seems to be drawing a fullscreen image that causes it (though the image is drawn fine for a few frames). Stacktrace below which means nothing to me, any help appreciated...

```
I/DEBUG   (  836): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:1.5/CUPCAKE/150240:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  836): pid: 948, tid: 949  >>> com.bitbull.meat.android <<<
I/DEBUG   (  836): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000004
I/DEBUG   (  836):  r0 00000004  r1 4001d040  r2 00000004  r3 ad3296c5
I/DEBUG   (  836):  r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 ad33cce1  r7 41039fb8
I/DEBUG   (  836):  r8 100ffd00  r9 41039fb0  10 41039fa0  fp 00000001
I/DEBUG   (  836):  ip ad35b874  sp 100ffce8  lr ad3296cf  pc afb045a8  cpsr 00000010
I/DEBUG   (  836):          #00  pc 000045a8  /system/lib/libcutils.so
I/DEBUG   (  836):          #01  lr ad3296cf  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  836): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffca8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcac  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcb0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcb4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcb8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcbc  41f84728  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcc0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcc4  41f84728  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcc8  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffccc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcd0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcd4  410903b0  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcd8  100ffd30  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcdc  00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffce0  df002777  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffce4  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   (  836): #00 100ffce8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcec  ad3296cf  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcf0  100ffd20  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcf4  ad33ccf1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcf8  4001d040  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffcfc  ad00e3b8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd00  410903b0  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd04  00141858  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd08  ad33cce1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd0c  4001d040  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd10  00001071  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd14  00141858  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd18  100ffd20  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd1c  ad040a8d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd20  41039fb0  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd24  420000f8  
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd28  ad33cce1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
I/DEBUG   (  836):     100ffd2c  100ffd98  
I/ActivityManager(  568): Process com.bitbull.meat.android (pid 948) has died.
I/WindowManager(  568): WIN DEATH: Window{4360bbf8 com.bitbull.meat.android/com.bitbull.meat.android.MEATActivity paused=false}
I/WindowManager(  568): WIN DEATH: Window{4366abe0 SurfaceView paused=false}
W/InputManagerService(  568): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 948 uid 10019
```

Answer (score 1):

•On the OSX platform, if you manually remove the ~/.android directory using rm -rf ~/.android, then try to run the emulator, it crashes. This happens because the emulator fails to create a new .android directory before attempting to create the child SDK1.0 directory. To work around this issue, manually create a new .android directory using mkdir ~/.android, then run the emulator. The emulator creates the SDK1.0 directory and starts normally.

refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html) for details.